# Frequency plot last box of different width

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot of this [datafile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3ehi9hsnbp4fk0/known-ratio10-0.1-30-5-20-2.txt?dl=0)

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set key left top 
set size 1.4, 1.2
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color "Helvetica" 16
set grid ytics
stats 'known-ratio10-0.1-30-5-20-2.txt' u 1
set output "known_2I.eps"
binwidth=0.025
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + width/2.0
plot "known-ratio10-0.1-30-5-20-2.txt" using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes lc rgb "midnight-blue" title "2 sec  Interval"
```

[image]

The highest bar has half the width of the rest of bars.
I do not know if the height of that bar really due to the number of occurrences of the data file in the last bin or because is half the width.

I would like to have the same bar width in all the bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with the binning.  The plot style "with boxes" does not produce equal-width boxes by default (see documentation for details).  To specify a uniform box width use the command

```
set boxwidth 0.025
```